# header location in php not working

Tags: php, header, location, redirect

I am working on a web site. I am having one issue with my code. plz help me. 
This is my code. In this header location not working. It's working on my test server but not working on another server.

plz help.

```
    <?php
    include("../config/config.php");
    include("../classes/db.class.php");
    include("../classes/functions.php");
    extract($_POST);
    $data=userLogin($vUsername,$vPassword);
    if($data!="")
    {
        if($data['eStatus']=='Inactive')
        {
            $_SESSION['error']='Your account is pending for approval.';
            header('Location:../login.php');
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
            {
                $_SESSION['userData'][$key]=$value;
            }
            deleteUnpaidOrder($_SESSION['userData']['iUserID']);
            clearCart($_SESSION['userData']['iUserID']);
            $_SESSION['success']='welcome '.$data['vFname'].' '.$data['vLname'].'!';
            if($data['iOrganizationTypeID']==3 || $data['iOrganizationTypeID']==2 || $data['iOrganizationTypeID']==5)
                header('Location:../location.php'); 
            if($data['iOrganizationTypeID']==1)
                header('Location:../exclusiveOpportunityForShopOwners.php');    
            if($data['iOrganizationTypeID']==4)
                header('Location:../manageInStoreAdvertising.php'); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['error']='Username or Password is wrong please try agian.';
        header('Location:../login.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What actually happens? What do you see if you monitor the request in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools? Do you see the request for the first page being made? Does it get a response? Does the response include the location header? Do you see the request for the second page? Does it get a response? Is the response correct? What do the server's log files say? What if you turn PHP error reporting up as high as possible? (NB: while most browsers will silently error correct, the Location header accepts only an **absolute** URI, not a relative one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ob_start();
session_start();

Write above two line on start of config.php file